# How to get shell script output into Makefile.am at make time?

Tags: autotools, autoconf, automake

I am working on an autotools project, and am a newbie to the autotools world. For various reasons, detailed at the bottom for completeness, I have a shell script from which I want to get the output for use in my makefile.

I have a situation similar to the following. Autoconf generates a script from an `AC_CONFIG_FILES` command. e.g.

```
AC_CONFIG_FILES([thescript], [chmod +x thescript])
```

thescript.in

```
#!/bin/sh
# -*- sh -*-
# @configure_input@
echo @abs_top_builddir@/bar/foo
```

What I really want to do is use whatever is returned by `@abs_top_builddir@/bar/foo` for use in my Makefile. I want to have this value available in a variable at make time and be able to access it in my Makefile.am as, say `$(FOOPLACE)`. How can I achieve this?

**Reason I require This / Extra Information**

This question is related to a previous question of mine located here:

[How to get absolute path to top build directory in autoconf configure.ac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15041754/how-to-get-absolute-path-to-top-build-directory-in-autoconf-configure-ac)

The project requires a subproject which has its own makefile and configure.ac. The subproject is a program which is used to generate source files for the main project. There is an option to disable the building of this project and attempt to use an installed version instead. In this case, the location of the installed version is provided in the variable `FOOPLACE` (uisng `AC_PATH_PROG`). When I am using the locally built verision I want to put the location of it in `FOOPLACE` instead. The variable is then used in Makefile.am as `$(FOOPLACE)`.

It seems there is a bug in autoconf which means the only place that abs_top_builddir can be accessed is in configure files generated by `AC_CONFIG_FILES` at configure time. There are details of why I want to do this in the linked question.

Comment: What's wrong with the make variable `$(abs_top_builddir)`?

Comment: @WilliamPursell, I will edit the question to explain this.

Comment: @WilliamPursell, I've now edited, I am open to entirely different solutions if you have an idea. I am new to this.

Comment: I hope you're not trying to make the subdirectory modify the parent directory, because that way lies madness. Can you post a link to your project, or is it something internal? If I had more idea about your project's structure I think I can give you an answer.

Comment: @JackKelly, It's not internal, it is the GPL Qucs project (http://sourceforge.net/projects/qucs/). Specifically, qucs-core. There is a subproject adms in qucs-core which is what must normally be used.

Comment: @JackKelly, For further info, I'm not trying to modify anything. I want the option to either build and make use of a subproject (ADMS) which has it's own Makefile.am and configure.ac, or use a different installed version if the dev uses a `--disable-adms` option.

Comment: @JackKelly, oh, and it's the qucs-qt4 branch, not the main branch, forgot to say!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## The question as written

In your Makefile.am, you could do something like this:

```
foo.c: foo.in
        FOOPLACE=`./thescript`; $(FOOPLACE) -c -o $@ $<
```

That has the benefit of not requiring a GNU-ism in what is meant to be portable Makefile code.

## The right and hard way

I have prepared a dummy package that uses a tool called `mkfoo`. It can use the internal copy or the copy on the host's system.

Let's look first at `configure.ac`:

```
AC_PREREQ([2.67])
AC_INIT([parent], [0], [jack@jackkelly.name])
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE([foreign])

AC_ARG_WITH([mkfoo],
  [AS_HELP_STRING([--with-mkfoo],
    [Path to mkfoo, "external", "internal", or "check" @<:@check@:>@])],
  [MKFOO=$withval],
  [with_mkfoo=check])
AS_IF([test "$with_mkfoo" = check -o "$with_mkfoo" = external],
  [AC_PATH_PROG([MKFOO], [mkfoo], [no])])
AS_IF([test "$with_mkfoo" = external -a "$MKFOO" = no],
  [AC_MSG_ERROR([External mkfoo demanded, but not found.])])

dnl We conditionally set MKFOO in Makefile.am
AM_SUBST_NOTMAKE([MKFOO])

AM_CONDITIONAL([USE_INTERNAL_MKFOO],
  [test "$with_mkfoo" = internal -o "$MKFOO" = no])
AM_COND_IF([USE_INTERNAL_MKFOO], [AC_CONFIG_SUBDIRS([mkfoo])])

AC_CONFIG_FILES([Makefile src/Makefile])
AC_OUTPUT
```

There are a few things going on here:

1. The default behaviour is "check for mkfoo, if it's not there, build and use the bundled copy". Note also that it supports `--with-mkfoo=PATH` (user may have a copy installed in an odd place), `--with-mkfoo=internal` (needed for distcheck, where we want to test everything) and `--with-mkfoo=external` (a kindness to package maintainers, who don't like bundled subprojects).
2. `AM_SUBST_NOTMAKE([MKFOO])` stops `automake` from generating a line of the form `MKFOO = @MKFOO@` in `Makefile.in`. We need to do that assignment conditionally.
3. We set up an automake conditional because we need to do different stuff for internal/external `mkfoo` inside `Makefile.am`
4. We configure the `mkfoo` directory conditionally.

Now, the toplevel `Makefile.am`:

```
if USE_INTERNAL_MKFOO
SUBDIRS = mkfoo
DIST_SUBDIRS = mkfoo
else
SUBDIRS =
DIST_SUBDIRS =
endif
SUBDIRS += src
DIST_SUBDIRS += src

## Need to make sure the internal tools work during distcheck.
DISTCHECK_CONFIGURE_FLAGS = --with-mkfoo=internal
dist-hook:
if ! USE_INTERNAL_MKFOO
        cp -fpR $(srcdir)/mkfoo $(distdir)
endif
```

What's going on here:

1. Conditionally recurse into `mkfoo`, and do it before `src`, which needs `$MKFOO`.
2. Because there are times `mkfoo` is *not even configured*, it might not have a `Makefile`. That means we've broken `make dist` (and by extension, `make distcheck`). So we have to set `DIST_SUBDIRS` conditionally as well, and if we don't have `mkfoo` configured ensuring that it's distributed becomes our responsibility.
3. When we `make distcheck` we want to use the internal copy because it's better to exercise everything in the source tarball.

Now, `src/Makefile.am`:

```
if USE_INTERNAL_MKFOO
MKFOO = $(abs_top_builddir)/mkfoo/mkfoo
else
MKFOO = @MKFOO@
endif

bin_SCRIPTS = foo
CLEANFILES = foo
EXTRA_DIST = foo.in

foo: foo.in
        $(MKFOO) < $< > $@
```

There is nothing shocking here except the conditional assignment of `MKFOO`.

`src/foo.in`:

```
I am foo.in!
```

Now for the subpackage. `mkfoo/configure.ac`:

```
AC_PREREQ([2.67])
AC_INIT([mkfoo], [0], [jack@jackkelly.name])
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE([foreign])
AC_PROG_CC
AC_CONFIG_FILES([Makefile])
AC_OUTPUT
```

As you can see, nothing special. What about `mkfoo/Makefile.am`?

```
bin_PROGRAMS = mkfoo
```

`mkfoo/mkfoo.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  puts("Internal mkfoo.");
  return 0;
}
```

Just a dummy test program.

Comment: One thing I forgot to mention, in the real case the subproject is only required for devs, it is used to generate some source code. It is not required for distributions, which would just ship the created code,so `make dist` does not need to include `foo`.

Comment: Then I'd break the build tool out into a project of its own. Require devs to have it installed and take all the black magic out of your main project.

Comment: I will consider this going forward. The problem is a version of this project compatible with the main project is difficult to obtain. The version at the home of the subproject has been deliberately made difficult to use/understand, and newer forks are incompatible.

Comment: Have a look at adl's answer for a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15241453/429232 . He always configures the subdir, but only conditionally adds it to `SUBDIRS` which means `make dist` doesn't break. It might be a smarter way to go.

Comment: I used the "easy" way and saved my life :) Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

what does not work with the following line in your Makefile.am?

```
FOOPLACE=$(shell @abs_top_builddir@/thescript)
```

Comment: `FOOPLACE` is generated by a condition, see the details in my linked question for why I cannot do this.

Answer (score 0):

`FOOPLACE` seems to be created by its presence in configure.ac in a conditional, even if the condition is not true (see the linked question for details). It is therefore present but empty at make time. It also seems variables cannot be redefined in the Makefile.am, however, they can be appended to. Since `FOOPLACE` is empty, the output from the script can be added to it with the following.

```
FOOPLACE+=$(shell $(abs_top_builddir)/thescript)
```

Comment: If someone suggests a better answer, I will be happy to accept it!

Comment: Jack Kelly added the real answer above.